# Section Name: "Technical Background" vs. "Technical Backgrounds"?

Tags: grammar

In an academic context, how to name a section about **multiple** background or more basic topics: "Technical Background" vs. "Technical Background**s**"?

Comment: *Multiple background* does not sound right. *Technical Backgrounds* does if you address a number of them.

Answer (score 0):

There can be various sub-topics included under a heading of *Technical Background*, so this would be the preferable section heading, generally.

However, it's theoretically possible that you really would need something to function like a plural.  In that case, I'd propose something like

Technical Background of [for example] the Three Methods Used [or Employed or Utilized]

The only situation I can think of where I would allow myself (maybe) to use the plural would be something like three different paintings, all with the same foreground, but different backgrounds.